# dygraphs JavaScript distance between dates

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/7027/

```
  g = new Dygraph(

// containing div
document.getElementById("graphdiv"),


// CSV or path to a CSV file.
("Response Time,Loop\n" +
"09/02/2015,175\n" +
"09/04/2015,170\n" +
"09/06/2015,180\n" +
"09/08/2015,177\n" +
"09/11/2015,179\n"+
"09/30/2015,165\n"),
  {

strokeWidth: 3,  


  }
```

);

Is it possible in dygraphs to set the same distance between x-axis values?

I want to set the same line length among all points no matter of the date time space.

Comment: So why are you using these dates in the first place? you can't have a non-linear axis, but you can have linear x values.

Comment: I need to print different dates with values, but I want the lines to have the same length. No matter if there is a difference of one day, 4 days or one year between those dates

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That's not how it's done (by people who know what they're talking about). It means the overall shape of the graph depends more on the sampling method (which days were sampled). For instance, if you have a graph that's going up but you want to know whether it's accelerating or decelerating, you'd just check which way the graph is curved. So I recommend you let dygraphs do its thing.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can get it to fully work as your requirement is against how data is arranged on graphs, but you can use parse & format callbacks to come close:

```
var i = 0;
var labels = [];
g = new Dygraph(
// containing div
document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
// CSV or path to a CSV file.
("Response Time,Loop\n" +
    "09/02/2015,175\n" +
    "09/04/2015,170\n" +
    "09/06/2015,180\n" +
    "09/08/2015,177\n" +
    "09/11/2015,179\n" +
    "09/30/2015,165\n"), {
    strokeWidth: 3,
    xValueParser: function (str) {
        console.log(str);
        labels[++i] = str;
        return i;
    },
    axes: {
        x: {
            valueFormatter: function (i) {
                return labels[i];
            },
            axisLabelFormatter: function (i) {
                return labels[i];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/7028/)

Comment: Thanks. But the dates now are not shown, why is that?

Comment: Because you probably can't really do it as I wrote. There's a reason things work like they do, and when you try really hard to bend them, they eventually break. In this case - it's the axis labels. I truly believe this is as close (or nearly as close) as you're going to get, and I encourage you to change your requirements, or change a library.

Comment: The reason that your axis labels aren't showing up is that you're using the x-axis ticker, which doesn't make much sense in this context. You can override that to get your dates to display. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/7031/).

Comment: @danvk - nice, but I feel you have some home-court advantage here :-) Plus, it's not *exactly* the same result as letting the built-in functionality work it's magic and *go to great lengths to choose good tick marks*.